# How do you make a one scroll page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do you make a one page scrolling site like [this](https://www.apple.com/uk/iphone-5s/).
I tried using "peachananr" plugin from [here](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) but it didn't work instead it messed up my layout.
Eg after doing:

```
<div class="main">
<section id = "mainPage" class="container mainPage" >
</section>

<section id = "projectContents" class = " projectContents" >
<span style = "display: block; float: left; margin-top: 50px; font-size:40px; font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;">
 Projects:
</span>
</section>
</div>
```

My whole page came together o.O ! (all sections came together in one) my page is basically a one page website like [this](https://www.http://hackcampus.io/)

This is my css for the way i layout each section page:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* look this up */
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}


.mainPage {
height:100%;
width:100%;

background: url(Imgs/13.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;

-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;

}

.projectContents {
position: relative;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background: white;

}
```

This is my Html:

```
<section id = "mainPage" class="container mainPage" >
</section>

<section id = "projectContents" class = " projectContents" >
<span style = "display: block; float: left; margin-top: 50px; font-size:40px; font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;">
 Projects:
</span>
</section>
```

Please how do i resolve this issue or can you please give any solution. Examples will be greatly appreciated !! :D Thanks alottt !

ps i call the plugin in my js file like so $(".main").onepage_scroll();

[image: This is what happens when i use the plugin]

Comment: Where do you call the plugin?

Comment: in my javascript file

Comment: can you put this into a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are loading the onepage-scroll css and javascript... It works fine without any of your CSS. Style from there.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
<section id = "mainPage" class="container mainPage" >
</section>

<section id = "projectContents" class = " projectContents" >
<span style = "display: block; float: left; margin-top: 50px; font-size:40px; font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;">
 Projects:
</span>
</section>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.main').onepage_scroll()
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J3Rxz/1/)**

Comment: please look at the screen shot i uploaded i added the onepage-scroll css thats what i got afterward :(

Answer (score -1):

Make bind to mouse scroll, and create slides.

```
<div class="b-slider">
   <div class="b-sider__item">
      Item 1
   </div>
   <div class="b-sider__item">
      Item 2
   </div>
   <div class="b-sider__item">
      Item 3
   </div>
   <div class="b-sider__item">
      Item 4
   </div>
   <div class="b-sider__item">
      Item 5
   </div>
</div>
```

And use jcarousel slider plugin with vertical scroll options

```
$('.b-slider').jcarousel('next');
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't really have a background with scrolling pages but I found [this site](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/) that might help you in your code.

> The structure is quite simple, adding a `section` class for each section of the site, and `slide` for each slide within a section:

```
<div id="fullpage">
     <div class="section">WHATEVER</div>
     <div class="section">WHATEVER</div>
     <div class="section">
          <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
          <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
          <div class="slide">Slide</div>
          <div class="slide">Slide 4</div>
     </div>
     <div class="section">WHATEVER</div>
</div>
```

> To initialize the plugin with default options, is as simple as this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage();
});
```

Here is an example: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ok, will do next time.